# Override tsconfig.json in a VS2019 solution/MSBuild?

Tags: typescript, msbuild, visual-studio-2019, tsconfig

I have a Visual Studio solution (not VS Code) with multiple `tsconfig.json` files that I want to behave differently in production.

I want to have two files (maybe more) something like:

1. `tsconfig.json` default settings for this part of the solution:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    ...
  },
  ... lots more settings
}
```

2. `tsconfig.release.json` override those settings to exclude comments and source maps:

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": false,
    "removeComments": true
  }
}
```

How to I tell VS2019/MSBuild to use the `tsconfig.release.json` override when doing a release build or publish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a way to do this, but it's horrible and I'd happily accept a better answer.

`tsc` can take custom config file names, but you can only run it from MSBuild if you add `<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>` to the project file and add something else to run it.

MSBuild can have different options for Release vs Debug, but *only* if it owns all the Typescript config and there are no files called `tsconfig.json` anywhere in the project.

MSBuild *can* find any `tsconfig.json` at any folder depth, but can't find any other file name - `tsconfig.release.json` or `tsconfig.debug.json` are out.

MSBuild can also change the rules for what files it includes, so the solution:

- Move the release overrides to a folder, so `tsconfig.release.json` becomes `releaseConfig/tsconfig.json`. It now needs some relative paths to find the project:

```json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": false,
    "removeComments": true
  },
  "include": [ "../**/*" ]
}
```

- Next we need two changes to the `.csproj` file. First we stop this config from being picked up in non-release builds:

```xml
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'!='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <Content Remove="whatever\releaseConfig\tsconfig.json" />
    <None Include="whatever\releaseConfig\tsconfig.json" />
</ItemGroup>
```

- Finally in the release build we swap the files:

```xml
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <Content Remove="whatever\tsconfig.json" />
    <None Include="whatever\tsconfig.json" />
    <None Remove="whatever\releaseConfig\tsconfig.json" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The default `tsconfig.json` is removed from `<Content>`, but needs to be `<None>` so the relative paths in `releaseConfig\tsconfig.json` to still find it.

Comment: Since you have a workaround about this issue, I suggest you could mark your own answer:)

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT yeah, I had to wait 2 days first :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ran across a similar issue.  After poking around in the guts of the TypeScript NuGet, I decided on this, which I've stuffed into `Directory.Build.targets` in a parent directory.

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="FindConfigFiles"
          Condition="'$(DesignTimeBuild)' != 'true'">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ConfigFiles Include="**\tsconfig.json" KeepDuplicates="false" 
                   Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'" />
      <ConfigFiles Include="**\tsconfig.Development.json" KeepDuplicates="false"
                   Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

I use explicit file names, but in the above, I've prefixed the `Include`s with `**\` (match in any subdirectory), for any others that googled their way here.

Comment: do you explicitly import this file into the csproj that is using it or is it picked up by some convention?